# Dismiss popup window from Fragment like onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I would like to dismiss a popup window when the user presses the back button. Since i am in the context of a Fragment i don't have the method `onBackPressed()` available.

Dismissing the popup shouldn't be something difficult as i just need to call the `dismiss()` method. Problem is i don't know how to detect the pressing of the back button

Could i use something similar for a Fragment or is there any other way i can detect the pressing of the Back button from this Fragment?

Thanks!

**LATER EDIT => WHAT I TRIED TO DO**

In my main activity i implemented the `onBackPressed()` method like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //isThePopupShowing() is a method in the target fragment which returns true if the PopupWindow is currently showing
    if (secondFragment.isThePoupShowing()) {
        // dismissPopup is a method in the same fragment which closes the PopupWindow with the dismiss() method
        secondFragment.dismissPopup();
        Log.d("DismissPopup", "And finally here!");
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

when i create the fragment here:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    SharedPreferences user_details = getSharedPreferences(
            ro.gebs.captoom.utils.Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);

    LoginFragment firstFragment = new LoginFragment();
    secondFragment = new HomeScreenFragment();

    String userid = user_details.getString("userid", null);

    manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (userid == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, secondFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

This is the code in my fragment:

```
public boolean isThePoupShowing() {
    return sync_popup != null && sync_popup.isShowing();
}

//
public void dismissPopup() {
    Log.d("DismissPopup", "I got here, dismissing");
    sync_popup.dismissPopup();
}
```

And this is the dismiss method:

```
public void dismissPopup(){
        layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        dismiss();
        Log.d("DismissPopup", "and in SyncQuickAction");
    }
```

The back button works normally as the application closes once i press the back button when the fragment is open but the popup is not dismissed when i press the back button... any suggestions as to what i might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What's stopping you from implementing the dismiss code in the `onBackPressed()` method of the `Activity`?

Comment: I kind of need to call super.onBackPressed() there since i need to exit the app somehow... but could you be more specific please i am not sure i understood:)

Comment: what is 'popup'? for dialogs you usually have the dialog.setCancelable(true); option

Comment: Something like this https://gist.github.com/luksprog/6712824

Comment: It's a class that extends PopupWindows...

Comment: Did you used a custom `PopWindow`? or what's the deal with the `sync_popup.dismissPopup();` call.

Comment: Yes i have a custom class that extends popupwindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fragment is paused ([lifecycle of fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating)) when the popup window is showing, so sync_popup gets null value and isThePoupShowing method always gets false value when it's called from the activity.

When you make the popupWindow as a static member, the system will not "recycle" the member when the fragment is paused and you can dismiss it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);
```

with this

```
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
```